# Install OpenCV-2.4.9 on CentOS 7 (PC)

Tags: linux, opencv, centos

I'm trying to install OpenCV-2.4.9 on CentOS 7 (PC) however getting error after 16% when running "make" command. I leave default configuration for OpenCV.

```
    make
    ...
 [ 16%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_v4l.cpp.o /opt/opencv-2.4.9/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_v4l.cpp:306:29: error: field ‘capability’ has incomplete type
         struct video_capability capability;
                                 ^ /opt/opencv-2.4.9/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_v4l.cpp:307:29: error: field ‘captureWindow’ has incomplete type
         struct video_window     captureWindow;
    ....
    ....
    /opt/opencv-2.4.9/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_v4l.cpp: In function ‘void icvCloseCAM_V4L(CvCaptureCAM_V4L*)’:
    /opt/opencv-2.4.9/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_v4l.cpp:2812:46: error: ‘CvCaptureCAM_V4L’ has no member named ‘memoryBuffer’
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the define HAVE_CAMV4L has the value 1, if you look in the file modules/highgui/src/cap_v4l.cpp looking for the structure definition at the row 306. If the compilation fails at that point this means that the video4linux development configuration is corrupted.

Using google I have found that the OpenCV Bug #1357 is described as follow:

CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE(linux/videodev.h HAVE_CAMV4L) succeeds even though linux/videodev.h doesn't exist on the system. (Bug #1357)

http://code.opencv.org/issues/1357

Anyway the solution is described at the same URL for "HAVE_CAMV4L gets set incorrectly": "Setting it to FALSE in CMakeLists.txt fixes the problem".